# Not able to access remote database

Tags: codeigniter, wamp, codeigniter-2

I am trying to use a remote database for my codeigniter project (I am using WAMP).I get the following error when I try to bring up my controller page:

> A Database Error Occurred Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. Filename:
>   C:\wamp\www\Naranpur\system\database\DB_driver.php Line Number: 124

These are my database file settings:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'something.cs.something.edu';
$db['default']['port'] = '3306';
$db['default']['username'] = 'some_user';
$db['default']['password'] = 'some_pwd';
$db['default']['database'] = 'some_database';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'latin1';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

But when I try to access the database on my localhost with the following settings and give the same url, it works!

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['port'] = '3306';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'test';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'latin1';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Could someone please tell me where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to give the user `some_user` the privilege to access your database.
from your `phpmyadmin` got to `privilege` tab and then edit the privilege for this user.
In the login information section set the host to your IP address or set it to `%` to allow this user to access from any host.

Comment: what are you mean about 'says no privileges' ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you access to something.cs.something.edu from a mysql client? (to check the connection)

Comment: when I give something.cs.something.edu/phpmyadmin in the url. and try to login with the above details. it works.

Comment: Try with a mysql client, maybe the administrator didnt enabled external access to the 3306 port

Comment: I am using WAMP. My mysql console directly points to localhost :/

Comment: Ok, the site will be located on: something.cs.something.edu (the files and database), when that happens you will connect using localhost without any problem. If you want to try it for a different location (like using wamp on your PC, you need the ports on that location accessible from internet)